# Convert rows to columns to remove duplicate entries on common value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, dataframe, row, data-cleaning

I’m a beginner to SQL and trying to figure out how to convert data to a column to remove duplicate entries. I’ve tried pivot, but I don’t need to aggregate values. Any help would be appreciated.

Current state:

| ClientID | AddressType | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Home | AU |
| 10001 | Postal | NZ |

Target state:

| ClientID | Home | Postal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | AU | NZ |

Comment: Use conditional aggregation.

Comment: What if there are multiple rows for the same address type for the same client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this using `aggregation` of a `case expression`

```
select clientId, 
    Max(case when AddressType='Home' then Country end) Home,
    Max(case when AddressType='Postal' then Country end) Postal
from clients
group by ClientId
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggregation is a very reasonable approach to the problem.  But if you prefer an alternative approach, you can use `join`:

```
select th.clientid, th.country as home, tp.country as postal
from t th join
     t tp
     on th.clientid = tp.clientid and
        th.addresstype = 'Home' and
        tp.addresstype = 'Postal';
```